# JS doesnt work in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My Javascript doesn't work in my Google Chrome extension.
I never worked with Google Chrome extensions before and I don't know how to handle this problem. I want to embed JS in my HTML, but it just doesn't work. We see the calculator, but the buttons do anything. Even if we type in some numbers and press enter, the numbers will be deleted and nothing happens.

Here my HTML and JS:

Home HTML

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>AFMO</title>
        <style>
            body {
                min-width:200;
                min-height:400;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="calculator.html">Calculator</a>



    <p>
        <id="Links">
        <a href="calculator.html" target="_Calculator2"><img src="icon/twitter.png" width="64" height="64"/></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_Twitter"><img src="icon/twitter.png" width="64" height="64"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_Facebook"><img src="icon/facebook.png" width="64" height="64"/></a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/" target="_Instagram"><img src="icon/instagram.png" width="64" height="64"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/" target="_Youtube"><img src="icon/youtube.png" width="64" height="64"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.blogger.com/" target="_Blogger"><img src="icon/blogger.png" width="64" height="64"/></a>
        <a href="https://vimeo.com/" target="_Vimeo"><img src="icon/vimeo.png" width="64" height="64"/></a>
        </id>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

linked HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Taschenrechner</title>
<style type="text/css">
.button {  width:60px; text-align:center;
           font-family:System,sans-serif;
           font-size:100%; }
.display { width:100%; text-align:right;
           font-family:System,sans-serif;
           font-size:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFE0" onload="calculator.js">

<form name="Rechner" action="" onsubmit="Ergebnis();return false;">
<table border="5" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
<input type="text" name="Display" align="right" class="display"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td  bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  7   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('7')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  8   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('8')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  9   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('9')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  +   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('+')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  4   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('4')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  5   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('5')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  6   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('6')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  -   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('-')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  1   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('1')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  2   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('2')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  3   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('3')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  *   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('*')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  0   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('0')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  .   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('.')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  =   " onclick="Ergebnis()"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  /   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('/')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="sqrt " onclick="Sonderfunktion('sqrt')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value=" pow " onclick="Sonderfunktion('pow')"></td>
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value=" ln " onclick="Sonderfunktion('ln')"></td>
<td><input type="reset"  width="60" class="button" value="  C  "></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    function Check (Eingabe) {
  var nur_das = "0123456789[]()-+*%/.";
  for (var i = 0; i < Eingabe.length; i++)
    if (nur_das.indexOf(Eingabe.charAt(i)) < 0)
      return false;
  return true;
}

function Ergebnis () {
  var x = 0;
  if (Check(window.document.Rechner.Display.value))
    x = eval(window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
  window.document.Rechner.Display.value = x;
}

function Hinzufuegen (Zeichen) {
  window.document.Rechner.Display.value = window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
}

function Sonderfunktion (Funktion) {
  if (Check(window.document.Rechner.Display.value)) {
    if (Funktion == "sqrt") {
      var x = 0;
      x = eval(window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value = Math.sqrt(x);
    }
    if (Funktion == "pow") {
      var x = 0;
      x = eval(window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value = x * x;
    }
    if (Funktion == "ln") {
      var x = 0;
      x = eval(window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value = Math.log(x);
    }
  } else
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = 0}
```

Some more Info:
This is our own Chrome app. We just copied the calculator, but we wont release this app, so i guess this doesnt matter.

EDIT
This comes in the console when i press any number on the calculator.
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following ""SEE BELOW"" Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
I already tried to fix this, and i cant even find any inline script.

""SEE BELOW""

Here stands the line of the button. If i press 7, there comes error in line 25, if i press 3 error in 39. I guess i have to put all the

```
<td><input type="button" width="60" class="button" value="  4   " onclick="Hinzufuegen('4')"></td>
```

in a extra js, but i dont really know how to do this

Comment: Could you specify your problem a little better? What do you mean by "my javascript won't work"? It calculates badly? It won't event start? Does it throw some kind of error? We're not wizards :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a **professional site** and as a result I have removed some of the junk in your question- please accept the edit. 
Please also make it clear whether this is your own Chrome extension, as this isn't clear. Does anything come up in the Chrome Developer Console?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `<script>` tag? 
It should be something like:

```
<script src="yourJSFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its in the body of the linked HTML
<body bgcolor="#FFFFE0" onload="calculator.js">

We have a HTML, the "Home HTML", its the main page. There is a button which should load a new page, the linked HTML and then it should display a Calculator. But the Buttons of the Calculator wont work, whatever we do, it doesnt work. I can upload the full App Folder if somebody needs it

Comment: You mean the body.onload?
It will not work unless you have a <script> tag as I mentioned

Comment: Well, we had a <script src="calculator.js"> </script> in our Calculator.html, the "linked HTML". But it still did not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a script tag within you head section

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jsfilehere.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: This is the head of the Calculator.html now, and it still doesnt work in our Chrome Extension.

    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
    <title>Taschenrechner</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     .button {  width:60px; text-align:center;
       font-family:System,sans-serif;
       font-size:100%; }
     .display { width:100%; text-align:right;
       font-family:System,sans-serif;
       font-size:100%; }
    </style>
    </head>